# minimal but extremely slow xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, oxygenxml

I have two xml files (one with 2000, the other with about 9000 items)  like this

```
<list>
    <mods ID="uuid-1...">
        <stuff/>
    </mods> 
    <mods ID="uuid-2..."/>
    ...
</list>
```

I use the following xsl to split each record into its own file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="list/mods:mods">
            <xsl:result-document method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" href="{./@ID}.xml">

                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />

            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for the smaller list this takes a few seconds until it completes, for the longer list it takes hours. It returns the desired result, but still is there a way to speed this up?
I use Saxon 9.6.0.5

Comment: How big are the items themselves? What happens if you just output a dummy tag instead of calling `<xsl:copy-of select=".">`?

Comment: @biziclop each item is between 2-4kb in the result file, they have between 15-25 elements as stuff.  I m not sure how to use a dummy tag?  `<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="list/mods:mods">
            <xsl:result-document method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" href="{./@ID}.xml">
            <dummy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </dummy>
            </xsl:result-document>` ?

Comment: Yes but without the `<xsl:copy-of select="." />`. It's just an experiment to see what takes so long: the sheer amount of data (>18 megabytes for 9000 records) or something else.

Comment: Maybe you have a some sort of antivirus that checks every new file generated by saxon?

Comment: As you have tagged the question as both saxon and oxygen I assume you use Saxon inside Oxygen. Have you tried to run Saxon from the command line, without Oxygen, to make sure it is Saxon that is that slow?

Comment: @biziclop I will try this once the transformation has completed in roughly two hours. I'm about half way through, and I would really like to get the results today. There are much larger files coming up ahead, so I will need to find a better solution. Thanks for the input

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson there is no antivirus programm installed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I ran the smaller file from the command line, it took about the same amount of time. There is sufficient resources left in the jvm of oxygen.

Comment: Maybe you have a some sort of fs scanning software, it should not be that slow.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it should be this slow. It's not a huge file and you aren't doing any complex processing on it. Do try running it outside oXygen just as an experiment. It's possible that oXygen is doing something with the 9000 result documents other than just writing them straight to disk.

Comment: I generated an XML input sample with XSLT with 9000 elements and then used code similar to yours to split it up into 9000 files. The timing with Saxon 9.6 HE and Java 1.8 from the command line with the `-t` option is `Execution time: 22.96085s`, with Saxon 9.6 EE (which I think uses threading of `result-document` to be faster) the timing is `Execution time: 8.046636s`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the comments here are some results, I m not a very technical person but I monitored cpu and memory usage when experimenting with the different suggestions. This is all on os x 10.10.4 Java 1.8.u51 saxon 9.6EE and 9.6HE.

The only thing that might have fs scanning on it was the transform script itself (not the data files) which is part of a git repo.  Completion time for the OP's transform: 11789.9s (3.27hours) using Saxon9.6EE from oxygen17.1.

Adding dummy elements -no change (didn't let it finish).

More tests today with different files containing 70 000 fragments all together 100mb of xml, using essentially the same xsl transform.

copying everything to a directory that was not part of an oXygen project (.xpr), or part of git: canceled after 1h but about the same speed.

using terminal Saxon 9.6HE: less time then it took me to refill my water glass, done in under 30 seconds for 70 000 items instead of 10 000.

I noticed that cli without specifying any xmx statements used up to 60% of my cpu and very little ram (2gb). Oxygen never used more then 30% of CPU and about 3gb of ram throughout the whole operation (with xmx in oxygen bumped to 4gb).

Thanks for the input, I m stunned how much faster command line is compared to using oXygen.